# Form size is not showing correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I am startin to build a winform application that uses a lot of the screen. So I put a form (size 2477,1402) and inside a Tab control (location 23,25, size 1883,1244)

However when running the program the tab's right border is too close to the form. In fact no matter how much you enlarge the form, the form size remains the same and if the tab control is enlarged the form hides part of the tab control space.

How can this problem be solved?

---

The designer code for the controls

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
            this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.tabPage2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.tabPage3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.btn60_1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btn60_2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btn60_3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btn60_4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btn60_5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btn60_6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btn60_7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btn60_8 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.tabControl1.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabPage1.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // tabControl1
            // 
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
            this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage3);
            this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
            this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1883, 1244);
            this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // tabPage1
            // 
            this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 28);
            this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
            this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1875, 1212);
            this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.tabPage1.Text = "tab1";
            this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // tabPage2
            // 
            this.tabPage2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 28);
            this.tabPage2.Name = "tabPage2";
            this.tabPage2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(2038, 1140);
            this.tabPage2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.tabPage2.Text = "tab2";
            this.tabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // tabPage3
            // 
            this.tabPage3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 28);
            this.tabPage3.Name = "tabPage3";
            this.tabPage3.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            this.tabPage3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1875, 1212);
            this.tabPage3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.tabPage3.Text = "tab3";
            this.tabPage3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btn60_8);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btn60_7);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btn60_6);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btn60_5);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btn60_4);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btn60_3);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btn60_2);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btn60_1);
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(22, 19);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(522, 466);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;

            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(10F, 18F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(2455, 1346);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "My program";
            this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
```

Comment: do you have a high dpi screen?

Comment: yes but the same thing happens in the primary screen of my laptop

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Can this answer help you?

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.AutoScroll = true;
    }
```